# How to paste RSIDs in CADD output

Tags: vcf, bedtools, variation

I want to paste RSIDs in CADD output as CADD does not give RSID column in its output. For this purpose I am using bedtools intersect to compare two files and have RSID column in my CADD file.

This is the command I am using.

```
bedtools intersect -a CADD.bed -b Input.vcf| cut -f 3
```

But this command is giving me error

```
ERROR: file CADD.bed has non positional records, which are only valid for the groupBy tool.
```

Is there any way to solve this error or any other way to get RSID column in CADD output file.

Comment: You might consider [vcfanno](https://github.com/brentp/vcfanno).

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you show us some line of your `CADD.bed` and `Input.vcf` and how your desired output should look like.

`bedtools` is complaining about non positional records in `CADD.bed`, which means there are lines in this file where the first three columns aren't `CHROM`, `START`, `END`.

I guess you will have some header lines in the beginning that aren't introduced by an `#`. Just delete them (or add in `#` to the beginning of the line) and try again.

fin swimmer